# VB.Net Passing values to another form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I would like to know how to pass a value from form1 to another form's public sub.
The problem is that it says "it is not accesible in this context because it is 'Private'."

I've tried changing Form 1 Private Sub to Public Sub but the same error remains. How should i make it work?

```
Public Class Form1
Dim test(), text1 As String
Const asd = "abcabc"

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    text1 = Space(LOF(1))
    test = Split(text1, asd)
    HOST = test(1)
End Sub
```

And i want to pass HOST = test(1) value to another form

```
Public Class Form2

Public Sub Check()
    'get the value to here
End Sub
```

Comment: I have encountered this question about ten thousand times on SO. It's mainly asked by VB programmers, not C# programmers. A WinForms form is just a class like any other Visual Basic class and you pass values from one form to another just the same way as you would pass a value from any class to any other class. As long as no multithreading is involved, there is no difference. You can pass values through constructor parameters (New), method (Sub and Function) parameters, properties or even by the means of events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass it as a parameter:

```
Public Sub Check(valueToCheck as String)
   'get the value to here
End Sub
```

Or create a property on **form2** to receive it:

```
private _HostOrSomething As String = ""
Friend Property HostOrSomething As String
   Get
        Return _HostOrSomething 
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _HostOrSomething = value
    End Set
```

In which case, Sub Check could use _HostOrSomething since it is local var.  To use these:

```
HOST = Test(1)
frm2.Check(HOST)
```

or

```
HOST = Test(1)
frm2.HostOrSomething = HOST
frm2.Check
```

Comment: So all of this code goes to form 2 only? or something to form 1 also?

Comment: just change `Sub Check` to take and argument like the first sample, then pass the value you want as an argument.

Answer (score -2):

You can use global variables to pass data from one from to another

```
        Dim A As New Integer= 10
```

Here how you declare the global The class can be define anywhere in the application.

```
Public Class GlobalVariables
Public Shared INTver As Integer
End Class
```

And how you use global variable to store the answer is here

```
GlobalVariables.INTver= A
```

put this lines in your "privet sub" and you can access the variable to any of your form that is in your WINDOWS application.

Comment: "*Calm down don't worry*"??? No need for attitude or patronizing here. And this question was asked (and answered) almost 4 years ago. Yet, you suggest using global variables (something the OP should legitimately worry about).

Comment: _"you have to use global variable"_ - Who says you _**HAVE**_ to use global variables?? (which infact aren't global at all, they're still bound to that class - just not to an instance). There are many other, and better, ways of doing this. Using a shared variable is in this case not effective at all and can actually disrupt the intended flow of the program if used incorrectly. I agree with @DavidMakogon that the OP should be worried. Instance solutions are preferred in this case.