# inter-Form communication in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, label, communication

I have a login form called `Admin`, which has a `Textbox1` for username and the main form called `Main`, which has a `Label1`.

My goal is for `Label1.Text` to display the current value of `Textbox1.Text`.

The login form has this succesfully working code:

```
Public Sub ShowDialogue()
    Main.Label1.Text = Textbox1.Text

End Sub
```

My problem is that the Main form code does not work, as follows:

```
Public Sub ShowDialogue()
    Admin.Label1.Text = Textbox1.Text

End Sub
```

the above code works when I use this code in main form to show the admin form.

```
Admin.ShowDialogue()
```

Since, I have changed the code in Main form to the following:

```
Using AdminNew as new Admin()
AdminNew.ShowDialogue()
End Using
```

Since this change, calling the value from `Textbox1` login form does not work.

Can somebody help me to figure out how to call the `Textbox1` on Main from the Admin form, even if I use the using block?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Global fields should generally be avoided but I would suggest that, in the case of something like the current user name, it is appropriate.  So, create a module and declare a property for the user name.  Set it from the login form after a successful login and then every other form can get it from there.

Comment: can you give me some example of that solution? I dont know much about vb.net. thanks

Comment: Looks like you might also be using default form instances.  You should get out of that habit ASAP.  Which of the 2 steps @jmcilhinney mentioned has you stumped a) create a module or b) add a property/field for the user name?  How far did you get?

Comment: @Plutonix, they got as far as asking someone else to do it for them so they don't have to think at all, of course.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have a theory that *Zork* would be a total flop today.  (probably dating myself)

Comment: @jmcilhinney, thank you for your suggestions, but I might correct you, posting in here is my last resort since I already tried what your suggesting based on some web tutorials I found,

Comment: and this is my answer, on module1 - Public strGlobalVar As String and in login form I set this module1.strGlobalVar = textbox1.Text and in admin form I added this code on form load Label1.Text = Module1.strGlobalVar,, so this answers my questions. anyway, thanks

Comment: We don't have ESP. If you've tried something and it didn't work then put that code in your question and tell us what happened. Obviously you did something wrong but, if we don't know what you did, then we can't know what's wrong with it.  Also, don't post unformatted code or any long code snippets in comments.  It's basically unreadable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.Net Passing values to another form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618668/vb-net-passing-values-to-another-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you can declare a public variable that you can use to store the username.

For Example.

1. create a module, then create a public declaration --

   ```
   Public _username as string
   ```
2. Create a form then pass the data to that variable

   ```
   _username = textbox1.text
   ```
3. pass the _username data to labeltext.

   ```
   Labeltext=_username
   ```

I think this answers your question specifically. thanks